# Simple Factory Design Pattern and injecting jpa repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to implement simple factory design patter within one of my projects. I am not quite sure where I should put logic which is interacting with `DB`. Normally I do:

```
@Component
public class Foo {
  private final BooRepository booRepository;
  public Foo(BooRepository booRepository){
    this.booRepository = booRepository;
  }
  void test(){
    List<Boo> booList = booRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

But putting such logic in `ConcreteProduct` is not an option trying to implement Simple Factory Design because `ConcreteProduct` is created with `new` in my case:

```
public static ScannerIntegrationFactory getProperScanner(ScannerPluginType type) {
    ScannerIntegrationFactory scanner = null;
    switch (type) {
        case DEPENDENCYTRACK:
            scanner = new DependencyTrack();
            break;
        case SPOTBUG:
            scanner = new Spotbug();
            break;
    }
    return scanner;
}
```

Could anyone give me a hint what is best way to interact with Database in this kind of pattern? should it be done on `ConcreteProduct` level somehow or `ConcreteProduct` should only return specific objects which later should be saved to DB? But how to make it work if `ConcreteProduct` was created with `new` keyword?
Or maybe should I simply create `Injection` of `JpaRepository` on top level and then pass it to each next factory?

Comment: You _may_ be looking for [Java SPI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html).

Answer (score 0):

If all the implementations extend the same parent interface then you could just use the Map Autowiring and return the implementation based on the type. for eg.

```
{
.
.
.
    @Autowired 
    Map<String, ScannerIntegrationService> scanners;

    public ScannerIntegrationService getScanner(ScannerPluginType type){
    return map.get(type.ToString());
.
.
.
}
```

Moreover, regarding the repository usage, each service implementation can use different repositories it needs by normal injection in their respective implementations.